# Eclipse and ADT : compiling XML files, very annoying

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, compilation, adt

I use Eclipse Juno with the latest version of ADT to make Android applications. To test the app, I obviously click on the "Run" button of the toolbar.

If I am currently editing a Java file, the device windows opens and I can run it normally. But, if I am editing an XML file, the Eclipse compiler inexplicably tries to *compile* the XML file, which will obviously not work.

It also creates a "myfile.out.xml", which generates tons of errors and I must restart Eclipse to delete it, because Eclipse is handicapped and can't delete a simple file ("An exception has beed caugh while processing the refactor 'Delete'" with a stupid reason like "an error occured while deleting resource").

It is being very annoying, and once I deleted the right file instead of the ".out" one ><

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to run the application instead of the XML file, even if I'm editing one of them?

Thanks for the help! I also read this: [Prevent Eclipse from building .xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493640/prevent-eclipse-from-building-xml-files) but the solution isn't working for me...

Comment: Do you happen to use a Mac or Linux?

Comment: In which directory is your xml file? (Project realtive should be fine)

Comment: Download the bundle with sdk and eclipse from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html this version solved this issue for me.

Comment: The XML files are in `res/layout`, `res/drawable`...

Comment: This happened to me when I was using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, Use Eclipse Classic instead.

Answer (score 0):

I find testing on my device so annoying. I edit a lot of files in assets folder and want to run my app to test (the java doesn't change and Run fails).

My solution is **Project > Build Automatically** then Run, i select my device and then check **Use same device for future launches**

Now the next time i want to test my app i **double click** the Run button executing 2 runs: **first click** results in Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front an the **second click** runs the app on the device as expected.

This way i don't have to ad spaces or code and then delete it to recompile my app.

### Run after XML edit

For Run to work i select from the eclipse editor the .java file or the manifest file and then click Run, while staying in the XML file, Run doesn't work.